# Scroll snaps to position of anchor link - unwanted behaviour and inefficient implementation

Tags: html, css, tabs, pseudo-class

I've created a simple tabbed content display using CSS and HTML. This code will be embedded around halfway down a much longer page with other content.

Here's the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ollyf/R9rq2/

I've made use of `:target` but I'm not entirely sure how it works. Read a few tutorials but I don't fully understand the behaviour. I feel like this is bad/inefficient code.

1. Is there a more efficient way to achieve this tabbed content effect?
2. If not, how can I reveal the content without the scroll position snapping to the top of the DIV?

Comment: I see you've been at this for a while. Your code seems fine so far - your use of `:target` doesn't seem problematic to me. Don't worry too much!

Comment: Thank you, really. I just don't feel confident. I don't feel like I fully understand it. But thanks for saying!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `:target` pseudo selector is triggered by on page anchors.  This means when your URL is http://www.example.com/#anchor1 `#anchor1:target` styles would be activated.  The page is also scrolled to the #anchor1 element.  This is the default functionality in browsers.

The other option for achieving a tab effect is through the use of javascript.  The concept is the same with javascript, you are still toggling the `display` attribute via click handlers.  There are several ready made scripts available for tabs.  Here is one example http://jquerytools.org/demos/tabs/index.html

Hope this helps clear things up.

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain a little more about `:target`? Specifically, if I target `#anchor1` I activate styles associated with that anchor. If I then target anything else (e.g. `#anchor2`) am I correct in understanding, it immediately resets/deactivates the styles activated when `#anchor1` was targeted?

Comment: @Olly F: That is correct, because then `#anchor1` is no longer the target.